# Built-in help in a Makefile

Tags: perl, makefile, make

My colleagues often ask me, "*Dude could you remind me what I have to type to build this target?*". So I eventually implemented a nice workaround in my Makefiles.

I wanted my Makefiles to have a help target that give some usage clues to the users. This is achieved with an embedded Perl script and some markers.

Wherever I want a target to be documented, I simply add this trailing comment:

```
##@<category> <description>
```

Here is an example:

```
SCRIPT_VERSION=v1.0
SCRIPT_AUTHOR=John Doe

all:                ##@Build Build all the project
     echo "Hello World!" > all 

clean:              ##@Cleaning Remove all intermediate objects
     rm all

mrproper: clean     ##@Cleaning Remove all output and interemediate objects

HELP_FUN = \
    %help; while(<>){push@{$$help{$$2//'options'}},[$$1,$$3] \
     if/^(\w+)\s*:.*\#\#(?:@(\w+))?\s(.*)$$/}; \
    print"$$_:\n", map"  $$_->[0]".(" "x(20-length($$_->[0])))."$$_->[1]\n",\
    @{$$help{$$_}},"\n" for keys %help; \

help: ##@Miscellaneous Show this help
    @echo -e "Usage: make [target] ...\n"
    @perl -e '$(HELP_FUN)' $(MAKEFILE_LIST)
    @echo -e "Written by $(SCRIPT_AUTHOR), version $(SCRIPT_VERSION)"
    @echo -e "Please report any bug or error to the author."
```

Here what I get if I type `make help`:

```
$ make help
Usage: make [target] ...

Miscellaneous:
  help                Show this help

Build:
  all                 Build all the project

Cleaning:
  clean               Remove all intermediate objects
  mrproper            Remove all output and interemediate objects

Written by John Doe, version v1.0
Please report any bug or error to the author.
```

In the case the Makefile takes time to parse the dependencies we can bypass the file for the `help` target:

```
ifeq (,$(filter help,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
# Core of the makefile
endif
```

What do you think of this technique. Is it a good approach? Can I improve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks pretty good to me, but I see a few minor things that might be improved.

### Specify which `perl` to run

I'd recommend not leaving it to chance as to which instance of `perl` is run.  Instead, for both safety and consistency, it might be better to do this:

```
PERL=/usr/bin/perl
##...
@$(PERL) -e '$(HELP_FUN)' $(MAKEFILE_LIST)
```

### Allow multiword category tags

With a slight change in your regex, multiword categories could be supported. If the second line is changed to this:

```
if/^(\w+)\s*:.*\#\#(?:@([^@]*)@)?\s(.*)$$/}; \
```

It will support multiword categories, delimited with `@`,

```
nothing:         ##@Odds & ends@ Do nothing, but gracefully
```

### Sort the keys for printing

On my machine, I get a different ordering each time I run `make help` which is a little confusing.  To fix that, sort the keys, rendering the last line:

```
@{$$help{$$_}},"\n" for sort keys %help
```

Note that you shouldn't have a line continuation there, and you don't need the trailing semicolon (although you may prefer one for style reasons).

### Omit declaration of hash

Because `%help` is unambiguously used, you don't need to predeclare it.  It will automatically be created as an empty hash, so the first line can become:

```
while(<>){push@{$$help{$$2//'options'}},[$$1,$$3] \
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a minor point, but you should declare all non-file targets as phony. Otherwise `make` will behave strangely if you have a file named named "all", "clean" etc in your directory. `make` will only run the command when the file is updated, which is not the desired behaviour.

```
.PHONY: all clean mrproper help
```

See [What is the purpose of .PHONY in a Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145590/what-is-the-purpose-of-phony-in-a-makefile) and the [GNU documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in pure make if you'd like (that is, without requiring an external tool like Perl).  John Graham-Cumming has a [detailed explanation](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/self-documenting-makefiles) of it on his blog, but here's the short version.

You can add documentation to a make target by declaring it like this:

```
include help-system.mk

all: $(call print-help,all,Builds everything)
    # commands go here

lib: $(call print-help,lib,Builds only the static library)
    # commands go here

clean: $(call print-help,clean,Removes intermediate and output files)
    # commands go here
```

Invoking `make help` will print out something that looks like:

```
Makefile:6: all -- Builds everything
Makefile:14: lib -- Builds only the static library
Makefile:20: clean -- Removes intermediate and output files
```

The contents of "help-system.mk" are listed at the link given above.

Note: the macro "print-help" expands to an empty string so this won't interfere with listing prerequisites for a target.